# Prompt 'Yes' every time to getFilings

Tags: r, for-loop, edgar

I am going to download the 2005 10-Ks for several corporations in R using the EDGAR package. I have a mini loop to test which is working:

```
for (CIK in c(789019, 777676, 849399)){
  getFilings(2005,CIK,'10-K')
}
```

However each time this runs I get a yes/no prompt and I have to type 'yes':

```
Total number of filings to be downloaded=1. Do you want to download (yes/no)? yes
Total number of filings to be downloaded=1. Do you want to download (yes/no)? yes
Total number of filings to be downloaded=1. Do you want to download (yes/no)? yes
```

How can I prompt R to answer 'yes' for each run? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remember to include a minimal reproducible example in your question, including `library(...)` and all other necessary commands:

```
library(edgar)
report <- getMasterIndex(2005)
```

We can bypass the prompt by doing some code surgery.  Here, we retrieve the code for `getFilings`, and replace the line that asks for the prompt with just a message.  We then write the new function (`my_getFilings`) to a temporary file, and `source` that file:

```
x <- capture.output(dput(edgar::getFilings))
x <- gsub("choice <- .*", "cat(paste(msg3, '\n')); choice <- 'yes'", x)
x <- gsub("^function", "my_getFilings <- function", x)
writeLines(x, con = tmp <- tempfile())
source(tmp)
```

Everything downloads fine:

```
for (CIK in c(789019, 777676, 849399)){
  my_getFilings(2005, CIK, '10-K')
}
list.files(file.path(getwd(), "Edgar filings"))
# [1] "777676_10-K_2005" "789019_10-K_2005" "849399_10-K_2005"
```

Comment: Nice.  Another way to replace that line would be `body(getFilings)[[6]][[3]][[3]][[3]][[8]] <- quote(choice <- "yes")`.  Crazy, but it works

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I will also include the library code as well next time.

Comment: @RichScriven, this is working great. Could you please elaborate on how to identify elements of the list? I would like to be able to use this approach for other functions too. (or if something changes in the package/function to affect precise numbering)

Comment: For example, for version 1.0.9, the correct line seems to be `body(getFilings)[[7][[3]][[3]][[3]][[8]]`

Comment: The call to `my_getFilings` should have named the `filing.year` argument since positionally is is third in the argument list.