# Download 10-k for each corporation, group by SIC code

Tags: r, finance, edgar

I am using the EDGAR library in R to download all 2005 10-Ks. The below code will prompt "yes" download the 10-K for each CIK in my loop. ([h/t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041077/prompt-yes-every-time-to-getfilings-in-r/42045389#42045389) to Weihuang Wong to assisting me with this.)

```
install.packages("edgar")

library(edgar) 

report <- getMasterIndex(2005)

x <- capture.output(dput(edgar::getFilings))
x <- gsub("choice <- .*", "cat(paste(msg3, '\n')); choice <- 'yes'", x)
x <- gsub("^function", "my_getFilings <- function", x)
writeLines(x, con = tmp <- tempfile())
source(tmp)

for(CIK in c(789019, 777676, 849399)){
 my_getFilings(2005, CIK, '10-K')
}

list.files(file.path(getwd(), "Edgar filings"))
```

I have downloaded [this mapper](https://www.valuespreadsheet.com/iedgar/cik-ticker.csv) and loaded it into R. It gives me the SIC industry # for each CIK code.

```
CIK <- read.csv("cik-ticker.csv")
```

How could I expand my code to look for a 10-K for every CIK on this list while grouping them by SIC code? I tried at defining CIK and SIC and creating a matrix but wasn't sure how to make my dimensions dynamic for the # of SIC codes I would get.

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you provided a short example of what you expect to be looked up and what the resulting output should look like.