# Using `lapply` to get multiple downloads/results

Tags: r, lapply

I have the following:

```
library(edgar)
setwd() 
years <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
masterIndex <- lapply(years, getMasterIndex)
```

Which creates two files to download data - and downloads an index.

I can also use the following:

```
NVDA  <- getFilings(2018, 0001045810, '10-K')
```

Which Will get me results for "NVDA" for 2018, the number 0001045810 corresponds to NVDA company.

I can also write:

```
msft <- getFilings(2018, 000789019, '10-K')
```

Which Will get Microsofts data.

I have a vector of these companies such as:

```
companies <- c("789019", "1045810")
```

So I want to `lapply` over this vector and get all of the companies within it.

I would also like to apply the same `lapply` to different years, i.e. all the years in the above `years` vector.

How can I go about doing this? The package askes also:

`Total number of filings to be downloaded=1. Do you want to download (yes/no)?
 yes`

Which I have to write `yes` - is there a way to "select" yes for all in the code?

My question is how can I use `lapply` to get a list of companies `NVDA`, `Microsoft` etc for each year?

i.e. one list for 2018, another for 2017 etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I still would like to `lapply` over a number companies though but the link suggested Will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function to get the data and use `outer` here

```
library(edgar)
years <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
companies <- c("789019", "1045810")

get_data <- function(x, y) getFilings(x, y, '10-K')

outer(years, companies, Vectorize(get_data))
```

Here, I am assuming you want to download data for `10-K` `form.type` for all.

---

Since, `options(needs.promptUser = FALSE)` doesn't work we can use the code given by @Weihuang Wong [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045389/3962914) to auto download everything without any prompt

```
x <- capture.output(dput(getFilings))
x <- gsub("choice <- .*", "cat(paste(msg3, '\n')); choice <- 'yes'", x)
x <- gsub("^function", "my_getFilings <- function", x)
writeLines(x, con = tmp <- tempfile())
source(tmp)
```

and then call `my_getFilings` in `get_data`

```
get_data <- function(x, y) my_getFilings(x, y, '10-K')

outer(years, companies, Vectorize(get_data))
```

Comment: Thanks!, I think this is working, however I have to type "yes" for every file downloaded. Setting `options(needs.promptUser = FALSE)` didn´t seem to work.

Comment: @user8959427 Updated the answer, see if it works now.

Comment: Running the following `supress <- capture.output(dput(getFilings))
surpress <- gsub("choice <- .*", "cat(paste(msg3, '\n')); choice <- 'yes'", supress)
supress <- gsub("^function", "my_getFilings <- function", supress)
writeLines(supress, con = tmp <- tempfile())
source(tmp)
years <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
cik_search("harley")
CIK <- c("63908", "793952")

get_data <- function(yr, cik) my_getFilings(yr, cik, '10-K')

outer(years, CIK, Vectorize(get_data))` still asks me to download each time.

Comment: It works at my end actually so I am not sure what might be wrong. One thing could be that I see you have used `supress` and `surpress` at different places. Is it just a typo while pasting here or you have actually used it in the script as well? You can correct it and re run again.