# r edgar Error: Input year(s) is not numeric

Tags: r, for-loop, numeric, edgar

I have a "test" dataframe with 3 companies (ciknum variable) and years in which each company filed annual reports (fyearq):

```
    ciknum  fyearq
1   1408356 2012
2   1557255 2012
3   1557255 2013
4   1557255 2014
5   1557255 2015
6   1557255 2016
7   1555538 2013
8   1555538 2014
9   1555538 2015
10  1555538 2016
```

After obtaining the MasterIndex folder and running [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041077/prompt-yes-every-time-to-getfilings) code (see proposed solution) I use the R edgar package to obtain 10-K filings. I run the following code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
  firm<-test[i,"ciknum"] #edit: seems like mistake can be here since new firm data only contains 1 obs of 1 variable
  year<-test[i,"fyearq"] #edit: seems like mistake can be here since new year data only contains 1 obs of 1 variable
  my_getFilings(firm,'10-K',year,downl.permit="y")
}
```

And it keeps spitting the following error: `Error: Input year(s) is not numeric`. I checked the variable type and it seems my fyearq variable is numeric.

```
sapply(test,class)
   ciknum    fyearq 
"numeric" "numeric"
```

Don't really understand why the "numeric" fyearq variable is not read as such by the my_getFilings function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @bartosz25 and M Grace,

I finally made it work through the following code:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(test)){
  firm <- as.numeric(test[row, "ciknum"])           
  year <- as.numeric(test[row, "fyearq"])
  my_getFilings(firm, c('10-K'), year, downl.permit="y")
}
```

Apologies for not posting it before.

Answer (score 0):

Martins
The ordering seems to matter here. I solved this problem by using the descriptor from the function, so that

```
my_getFilings(firm,'10-K',year,downl.permit="y")
```

as you wrote is written as

```
my_getFilings(cik.no = firm, form.def = '10-K', filing.year = 2016, downl.permit = "y")
```